# From inside of Kafka Consumer, how get the message header

Tags: apache-kafka, micronaut, micronaut-kafka

In few words, I want to get the message header listened by consumer but I am getting "Required argument [Header header] not specified".

Here is how I am trying unsuccessfully:

```
package com.tolearn.consumer

import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.Acknowledgement
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaKey
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.OffsetStrategy
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.Topic
import io.micronaut.messaging.annotation.Header

@KafkaListener(
        groupId="myGroup",
        offsetStrategy=OffsetStrategy.SYNC_PER_RECORD
)
class DemoConsumer {
    @Topic("demotopic")
    fun receive(@KafkaKey key: String?,
                msg: String,
                header: Header,
                acknowledgement: Acknowledgement

    ){
        println("Key = $key " +
               "msg = $msg " +
                "header = $header"
       )

        acknowledgement.ack();
    }
}
```

It prints this error:

```
00:02:05.890 [consumer-executor-thread-1] ERROR i.m.c.k.e.KafkaListenerExceptionHandler - Error processing record [Optional[ConsumerRecord(topic = demotopic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 6, CreateTime = 1607828525818, serialized key size = 36, serialized value size = 14, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = My-Header, value = [109, 121, 72, 101, 97, 100, 101, 114])], isReadOnly = false), key = 2afe3f0d-40c0-44f6-93a3-cce06678df80, value = name: "Hello"
)]] for Kafka consumer [com.tolearn.consumer.DemoConsumer@4ca2237e] produced error: Required argument [Header header] not specified
io.micronaut.core.bind.exceptions.UnsatisfiedArgumentException: Required argument [Header header] not specified
    at io.micronaut.core.bind.DefaultExecutableBinder.bind(DefaultExecutableBinder.java:88)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.processor.KafkaConsumerProcessor.lambda$process$8(KafkaConsumerProcessor.java:494)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

In case it adds something, here is the producer:

```
package com.tolearn.producer

import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaClient
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaKey
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.Topic
import io.micronaut.messaging.annotation.Header

@KafkaClient(
        id = "demo-producer",
        acks = KafkaClient.Acknowledge.ALL)
public interface DemoProducer {

    @Topic("demotopic")
    fun sendDemoMsg(
            @KafkaKey key: String?,
            @Header("My-Header") myHeader: String,
            msg: String?) {
    }

}
```

The service sending message with header throw producer

```
package com.tolearn.service

import com.tolearn.producer.DemoProducer
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Named
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class DemoService {
    @Inject
    @Named("dp")
    lateinit var dp : DemoProducer

    fun postDemo(key: String, msg: String){
        //blocking
        dp.sendDemoMsg(key, "myHeader", msg)
    }
}
```

I was expecting to print ... My-Header: myHeader

*** edit

For future readers, my soluiton became:

aplication.yml

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: demoGrpcKafka
  executors:
    consumer:
      type: fixed
      nThreads: 1
#kafka.bootstrap.servers: localhost:9092
kafka:
  bootstrap:
    servers: localhost:9092
  consumers:
    default:
      auto:
        commit:
          enable: false
  producers:
    #default:
    demo-producer:
      retries: 2
my:
  application:
    token: tokenFromYml
```

producer

```
package com.tolearn.producer

import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaClient
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaKey
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.Topic
import io.micronaut.messaging.annotation.Header

@KafkaClient(
        id = "demo-producer",
        acks = KafkaClient.Acknowledge.ALL)
        @Header(name = "X-Token", value = "\${my.application.token}")
public interface DemoProducer {

    @Topic("demotopic")
    fun sendDemoMsg(
            @KafkaKey key: String?,
            msg: String?) {
    }

}
```

consumer

```
package com.tolearn.consumer

import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.Acknowledgement
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.KafkaHeaders
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaKey
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.OffsetStrategy
import io.micronaut.configuration.kafka.annotation.Topic
import io.micronaut.messaging.MessageHeaders


@KafkaListener(
        groupId="myGroup",
        offsetStrategy=OffsetStrategy.SYNC_PER_RECORD
)
class DemoConsumer {
    @Topic("demotopic")
    fun receive(@KafkaKey key: String?,
                msg: String,
                headers: MessageHeaders,
                acknowledgement: Acknowledgement,
                offset: Long,
                partition: Int,
                topic: String,
                timestamp: Long

    ){
        val h = (headers).get("X-Token")

        println("Key = $key " +
               "msg = $msg " +
                "offset = $offset " +
                "partition = $partition " +
                "topic = $topic " +
                "timestamp = $timestamp " +
                "header = $h"
       )

        acknowledgement.ack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should try use *io.micronaut.messaging.MessageHeaders* and not just kafka Header class.

```
@Topic("demotopic")
fun receive(@KafkaKey key: String?,
            msg: String,
            headers: MessageHeaders,
            acknowledgement: Acknowledgement)
```

Also you can just specify value of header like on the producer side with *@io.micronaut.messaging.annotation.Header("My-Header")* in your consumer.

Don't forget to add *@javax.annotation.Nullable* if header is optional, or maybe just *String?* in case of Kotlin.

```
@Topic("demotopic")
fun receive(@KafkaKey key: String?,
            msg: String,
            @Nullable @Header("My-Header") myHeader: String,
            acknowledgement: Acknowledgement)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it is not poping up more execption after I add io.micronaut.messaging.MessageHeaders on consumer. Kindly, do you know how convert the header value to String? Headers came with "RecordHeader(key = X-Token, value = [116, 111, 107, 101, 110, 70, 114, 111, 109, 89, 109, 108])". [116, 111, 107, 101, 110, 70, 114, 111, 109, 89, 109, 108] must be equivalent to this word "tokenFromYml". Well, I tried headers.get(0).toString() but I get "The integer literal does not conform  to the expected  type CharSequence!"

Comment: Now it is working with (headers).get("X-Token"). I will add above whoel soluiton for future readers. You have answered my question. A last comment if you don't mind: what is the difference between use io.micronaut.messaging.MessageHeaders (your first code) and  io.micronaut.messaging.annotation.Header (your second code) ?

Comment: Yeap header value will be in bytes, that is cause Kafka serialize header values in bytes, you can easily convert to sting via new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF-8)

So for the first one, that is what Micronaut header value is registered for consumer and can be injected (there are specific registered types, and MessageHeaders is one of them)
And for the second this is basically +- same mechanism with more abstraction, it also uses MessageHeaders.get("My-Header") under the hook with validation just for simplification, 2 case can be validated via annotations.